# jQuery: How do I get a cloned div to always appear at the bottom of the container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to coding...

I'm trying to get divs to clone and end up in the section container on click. However, I want their order to be as they were clicked, not their position in the html.

For example, in the code below, click "show div 2" then "show div 1", note how "div1" goes above "div2" even though "show div 2" was clicked first.

My question is, how do I make the cloned div's position relative to the order it was clicked?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#showdiv1").click(function() {
    $("section").append($("#div1").clone(true));
    $("#div1").fadeIn("500");
    $("#hidediv1").fadeIn("500");
  });
});

$("#hidediv2").click(function() {

  $(this).closest("#div2").fadeOut("500");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#showdiv2").click(function() {
    $("section").append($("#div2").clone(true));
    $("#div2").fadeIn("500");
    $("#hidediv2").fadeIn("500");
  });
});

$("#hidediv2").click(function() {

  $(this).closest("#div2").fadeOut("500");
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

#showdiv1, #div1 {
background-color:salmon;
}

#showdiv2, #div2 {
background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section>
  <a class="button" id="showdiv1">Clone     Div 1</a>
  <a class="button" id="showdiv2">Clone     Div 2</a>
  <div id="div1">div 1 content<a id="hidediv1"> Hide Div</a></div>

  <div id="div2">div 2 content<a id="hidediv2"> Hide Div</a></div>
</section>
```

Comment: So you want div1 after div2 if div2 is clicked first ?

Comment: @melvin Yeah, on the first click, div1 always inserts itself before div2.

Comment: Note in James Hull's answer that he has put everything inside one `document.ready` function. This is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#showdiv1").click(function() {
    $(".div1").first().clone(true).appendTo("section").fadeIn("500");
  });
   $("#showdiv2").click(function() {
    $(".div2").first().clone(true).appendTo("section").fadeIn("500");
  });
  $(".hide").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("div").fadeOut("500").remove();
  });

});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

#showdiv1, .div1 {
background-color:salmon;
}

#showdiv2, .div2 {
background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section>
  <a class="button" id="showdiv1">Clone Div 1</a>
  <a class="button" id="showdiv2">Clone Div 2</a>
  <div class="div1">div 1 content<a class="hide"> Hide Div</a></div>
  <div class="div2">div 2 content<a class="hide"> Hide Div</a></div>
</section>
```

I think the issue is that you are using id selectors and attributes when you should really be using classes. The second click on the 'showdiv1' link is showing the hidden div you are cloning from as it is the first found with the id attribute.  I've updated the snippet. So I'm cloning the first div found with a certain class, appending it to the container and then showing. Also moved the other hide on click delegate inside the doc ready function so that works now too.

Comment: id's should only really exist once, but if they exist more than once, $('#id') will return the first found in the DOM.

Comment: I think first() and last() are only available in jQuery 1.4 up BTW

Comment: @JamesHull is right about `id`. And `#div1` will return only first matched element. But if you want all element with that id then you can use `attribute` selector like `$("section [id=div1]")` it will return all div with id as div1.

Comment: I would also consider using `remove()` rather than just hiding the element. Otherwise, the hidden element stays in the DOM, and if you keep showing and hiding you'll get a whole bunch of hidden elements that you have no use for. Like this: `$(this).closest("#div2").fadeOut("500").remove();`

Comment: @JamesHull Classes are certainly better practice when cloning elements. But I played around with using an id, wondering whether the selector in the click event handler would be able to find the right cloned element. Interestingly, it did. jQuery must do something internally to assign event handlers to the right cloned elements. Which makes sense when I think about it, because it would have to do the same thing if you use a class selector in the clone.

Comment: @JamesHull if I made the #showdiv1 a class and had multiple instances of the link on a page, would each link always create a clone of div1 below it?

Comment: @JamesHull or would I have to create a new function and "div1" in the html for each instance?

Comment: @KellyvanderHurk. You could do it. You would need each link in a `section` container and on the click event append the cloned div to the closest section container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insertAfter` and `attribute` selector like `[id=div1]` instead of `#div1`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#showdiv1").click(function() {
    if ($("section [id=div1]").length > 1) {      
      $("#div1").clone(true).insertAfter($("section [id=div1]:last"));
    } else {
      $("section").append($("#div1").clone(true));
    }
    $("[id=div1]:not(:first)").fadeIn("500");
    $("[id=hidediv1]:not(:first)").fadeIn("500");
  });
});

$("#hidediv2").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("#div2").fadeOut("500");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#showdiv2").click(function() {
    if ($("section [id=div2]").length > 1) {      
      $("#div2").clone(true).insertAfter($("section [id=div2]:last"));
    } else {
      $("section").append($("#div2").clone(true));
    }
    $("[id=div2]:not(:first)").fadeIn("500");
    $("[id=hidediv2]:not(:first)").fadeIn("500");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

#showdiv1,
#div1 {
  background-color: salmon;
}

#showdiv2,
#div2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section>
  <a class="button" id="showdiv1">Clone     Div 1</a>
  <a class="button" id="showdiv2">Clone     Div 2</a>
  <div id="div1">div 1 content<a id="hidediv1"> Hide Div</a></div>

  <div id="div2">div 2 content<a id="hidediv2"> Hide Div</a></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. Clicking on "Show div 2" first and then clicking on "Show div 1" still puts 1 above 2 the first time.

Comment: @Karan yeah, div1 is still nudging above div2?

Comment: @KellyvanderHurk Updated my answer.